# Which video format is right for `sendVideo` method in Telegram Bot API

Tags: video, telegram-bot

Which video format can be used in [Telegram Bot API `sendVideo`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvideo) method?

On the page they only mention "H.264/MPEG-4 AVC"

So if I convert a video (without sound) with

```
ffmpeg -i input -an -c:v libx264 -crf 26 out.m4v
```

I get an `ok:true` as response but I can't see the preview (blurred still image) in the Telegram client.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This was really driving me nuts: It's important that the file extension is **".mp4"**.
If you upload a video with ".m4v" extension you'll not see a preview window and the video is opened in an external player.

So here is my final command to reencode and resize a video and send it to the bot using curl:

```
ffmpeg -i input -an -c:v libx264 -crf 26 -vf scale=640:-1 out.mp4
curl -v -F chat_id=CHATID -F video=@out.mp4 -F caption=foobar https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendVideo
```

Comment: I am not sure where the problem is but using the exact same command generates videos that can be read by the desktop app but not with the android app. Any hint on why this happen?

Comment: @SimonC. Is it possible that you are using an old android version which doesn't support x264 decoding?

Comment: That may be an issue but I know of other user with newer phone that cannot watch the video. On another hand the telegram app have no problem reading the video made from the phone. I guess the phone is using another format? Another thing is that I am using ffmpeg from FreeBSD. Maybe the problem comes from freeBSD libx264 codec?

Comment: Adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` seems to make playback on Android work for me.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i "/home/folder/bangkok.avi" -c:v libx264 -crf 26 -vf scale=642:-1 -pix_fmt yuv420p16le out.mp4`
This works at desktop and on Android phone

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered in the thread [Which formats does Telegram internal video player support?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/172321/) of webapps.stackexchange

Recommendations on ffmpeg commands to optimize a video to run in the Telegram player.

**Essential**
Video codec: [x264 (avc)](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) or x265 (hevc)
audio codec: aac
audio channels: up to 2

**Recommended**
`max_muxing_queue_size 9999` - prevents memory allocation error during encoding for high-resolution videos. (Too many packets buffered for output stream)

`c:v libx264` - x264 codec, requires less CPU, avoiding crashes on old smartphones

`maxrate 4.5M` - Establishes maximum peak bitrate in complex scenes, to avoid crashes on a modest internet connection.

`crf 23` - Establishes a constant quality factor. Can be overridden by bitrate setting

`preset faster` - image optimization filter presets in the encode, which impacts the final size in a negative correlation with processing time. "Faster" delivers the best cost-benefit tradeoff according to the [trainer and author Jan Ozer](https://streaminglearningcenter.com/articles/)

`flags +global_header` - Adds global metadata to the file, useful to the player

`pix_fmt yuv420p` - Greater compatibility with older smartphones

`profile:v baseline` - Greater compatibility with older smartphones

`movflags +faststart` - Rearranges the output file so that essential metadata is placed at the beginning of the file

`c:a aac` - Audio codec required by Telegram

`ac 2` - Limits up to 2 audio channels (stereo). Above that, Telegram does not execute the file.

**Final command example:**

```bash
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -maxrate 4.5M -preset faster -flags +global_header -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -movflags +faststart -c:a aac -ac 2 "output.mp4"
```

For batch video optimization
[VIDQA](https://pypi.org/project/vidqa/) - Python library that performs batch video optimizations, compatible with Telegram

Answer (score 0):

Try adding -pix_fmt yuv420p, that made it work for me.

Note: taken from a comment from @Pastafarianist in this same question, which should be an answer instead.